# call component on nav.link href in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-bootstrap

i am new to reactjs, please help me to assign coponent AddApiComp to href of navlink to open on page load

```
import { Navbar,  Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

import AddApiComp from "./";

function Navigfgation(){

return(

\<Navbar collapse \>

\<Navbar.Brand href="#"\>Developer API\</Navbar.Brand\>
    

 \<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"/\>

\<Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav"\>
\<Nav className="mr-auto"\>

\<Nav.Item\>

\<Nav.Link href="./Add-Api-Controller" title="Add Api"\>{AddApiComp}\</Nav.Link\>

\</Nav\>
\</Navbar.Collapse\>


\</Navbar\>
)
}

export default Navigation;
```

on click of ** Add API**, *AddApiComp *component should display

Comment: I see you use "mr-auto" class. Are you using bootstrap version 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is not opinionated and does not include a routing solution. That's why you are free to use any of them. The most popular solution is "React Router". I have implemented a working example using your code and react router 6:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-6-example-ll16cx

Please follow this tutorial to understand the implementation: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

One tricky part is that you want to use frontend routing (without page reload, SPA) and at the same time having your bootstrap stylings on links. You can achieve this by using *Nav.Link* and using its *as* property:

```
import { Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/add-api-controller">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout [react router](https://reactrouter.com/) for navigation in React Applications